# Resize plot area in embedded chart object

Tags: excel, vba

I have problem resizing plot area in an embedded chart in excel

```
Dim myChart As Chart

maxPie = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Set myChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Shapes.AddChart.Chart


myChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
myChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(sheetName & "!$A$5:$C$" & maxPie)

With myChart.Parent
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 500
    .Width = 500
    .Height = 500
End With

With myChart.PlotArea
    .Top = 70
    .Height = 420
End With
```

if i press debug and then F5 then it resizes it, do I need to add a delay in my code because its not finished generating the plot area before I try to resize it

Comment: This kind of code can be a bit buggy. Sometimes adding a `DoEvents` call, or reading the `.Top` value into a variable first can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment Rory made about reading the value solved the issue, strange that this is needed though..

```
Dim temp As Integer
With myChart.PlotArea
    temp = .Top
    temp = .Height
    .Top = 70
    .Height = 420
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem why your code return error because PlotArea properies can only be modify after the Chart object if fully loaded. So yes, you need to complete Chart Object loading process and modify any PlotArea properties.
The code below will work. Try it..!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Demo()

    Dim maxPie As Long
    Dim myChart As Chart

    'I assume that your chart is on Sheet1
    maxPie = Sheet1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    Set myChart = Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart

    With myChart
        .ChartType = xlBarClustered
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$2:$C$" & maxPie)
    End With

    With myChart.Parent
        .Top = 10
        .Left = 500
        .Width = 500
        .Height = 500
    End With

    'Delay the SetPlotArea code execution using OnTime function
    Application.OnTime Now, "SetPlotArea", Now + TimeValue("0:0:5")

End Sub

Public Sub SetPlotArea()
    Dim ch As Chart
    Set ch = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart

    ch.PlotArea.Top = 70
    ch.PlotArea.Height = 420
End Sub
```

Comment: I prefer to pass ch as an object, not sure that is possible with your code, however Rory code worked, and then I do not have to add a fix delay, but your code works aswell:)

Comment: In programming world there are many ways to solve one problem, so choose the easiest and the fastest way.......Since Rory code's is more simple, I recommend that one.